# Cylinder Subdivision surface Modifier Problem

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm trying to make smooth hollow cyclinder with subdivision surface modifier but Blender goes to failure. Can I solve this problem or how can I make smooth hollow cyclinder ?
[image: Before the subdivision surface]

[image: after fail]

Comment: Looks like you have a big N-gon at each end, and you have an internal face in the middle (its right along the X axis).

Answer (score 1):

Avoid ngons (polygons with more than 4 vertices). They do not subdivide nicely.

You have a big and ugly ngon connecting the two rings. Delete that.

To connect concentric circles is easier to extrude and scale or use Bridge Edge loops. Both of them will give you topology based on quads. Those will deform correctly

[image]